# Why does fromRaw() return nil when I use a variable as an argument?

Tags: swift

When I use fromRaw on an enumerator with a variable that is assigned at compile time, like so:

```
int i = 3;
let tmpRank = Rank.fromRaw(i);
```

It works as expected. However, if I try the same thing in a for loop, like so:

```
for i in 0..3 {
    let tmpRank = Rank.fromRaw(i);
}
```

It doesn't work, and my playground returns nil for this line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is Rank.fromRaw(0) nil? your loop starts at 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Rank enum that was used in the swift book, there is no case that has a raw value of 0.

```
for i in 1..3 {
let tmpRank = Rank.fromRaw(i);
println(tmpRank)
}
```

That returns all enum values.

Comment: Gosh, I can't believe I got this one wrong. I just assuming that the for loop would still continue past 0, but apparently not. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It does continue for me, it's just hard to see it in the playground. You have to click for value history.

Comment: @evilgoldfish if you open the assistant editor to see the console and use the println you can see each one